# Outputting siteUrl consumes next closing tag

Tags: templating, siteurl, debugging

I'm running Craft Pro 2.3.2640.

Here is the code:

```
<span>{{ siteUrl }}</span>
```

Here is the output:

```
//localhost:3001/%3C/span%3E
```

The opening tag stays intact.

I am also struggling to use this variable with functions like "replace" when I need to parse the referral url.

Comment: Do you set it in config/general.php and why do you omit the "http:" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `siteUrl` in config/general.php like so.

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
    ),
    'localhost' => array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://localhost:3001/',
    ),
);
```

And then apply your replace filter.

```
<span>{{ siteUrl|replace({'localhost:3001': 'mysite.com'}) }}</span>
```